# No me admite implementar un FOR C#

Tags: c#, android, bucle-for, recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` en `Xamarin.Android` que funciona muy bien, el problema que tengo es que lo tengo seteado **manualmente** con un limite actual de 20 líneas o registros.

Esta es la clase donde se crea el "Album" que se usara en el Recycler.

Soy nuevo trabajando con Recyclers entonces me gustaria implementar en `public class PhotoAlbum` un `for` para no hacerlo manual sino **dinamicamente** para que pudieran ser mas de 20 registros o incluso 1 si lo quisiera (segun la cantidad de resultados de devuelva la query que se utilice para llenarlo).

Si intento agregar el for asi no mas me da el siguiente error:

**

> Invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

> El Token 'for' no es válido en una clase, estructura o declaración de
> miembro de interfaz.

**

Si necesitan que agregue algo mas por favor me lo hacen saber.

```
namespace RecyclerViewer
{
    public class Photo : Activity
    {           

        public string mPhotoID;

        public string mCaption;

        public string mTipo;

        public string PhotoID
        {
            get { return mPhotoID; }
        }

        public string Caption
        {
            get { return mCaption; }
        }

        public string TipoMaterial
        {
            get { return mTipo; }
            
        }       

        public class PhotoAlbum
        {
            
            public Photo[] mBuiltInPhotos =

            { //Mejorar con un FOR (i)
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[0], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[0], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[0] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[1], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[1], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[1] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[2], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[2], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[2] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[3], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[3], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[3] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[4], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[4], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[4] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[5], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[5], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[5] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[6], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[6], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[6] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[7], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[7], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[7] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[8], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[8], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[8] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[9], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[9], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[9] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[10], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[10], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[10] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[11], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[11], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[11] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[12], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[12], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[12] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[13], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[13], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[13] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[14], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[14], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[14] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[15], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[15], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[15] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[16], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[16], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[16] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[17], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[17], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[17] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[18], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[18], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[18] },
            new Photo { mPhotoID = Globales.ImagenesList[19], mCaption = Globales.NombresList[19], mTipo = Globales.TipoList[19] },                
            };          

            private Photo[] mPhotos;

            public PhotoAlbum()
            {
                mPhotos = mBuiltInPhotos;
            }

            public int NumPhotos
            {
                get { return mPhotos.Length; }
            }

            public Photo this[int i]
            {
                get { return mPhotos[i]; }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pon el código que te da error con el for para ver que pasa y tener una mejor idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es más un problema de diseño que con RecyclerView.

Lo que podrías hacer es modificar el constructor de PhotoAlbum para que le pases los datos justo cuando se vaya a crear una nueva instancia:

```
      public class PhotoAlbum
      {
         Photo[] Fotos;
         public PhotoAlbum((string[] imgs, string[] captions, string[] tipos) datos)
         {
            // Validar que tengan la misma longitud y no nulos

            int max = datos.imgs.Length;
            Fotos = new Photo[max];
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
               Fotos[i] = new Photo
               {
                  mPhotoID = datos.imgs[i]
                  , mCaption = datos.captions[i]
                  , mTipo = datos.tipos[i]
               };
            }
         }
      }
```

Y cuando vayas a crear un nuevo objeto:

```
// Arreglos con datos
string[] imgs = { "id1", "id2" };
string[] cap = { "cap1", "cap2" };
string[] tipos = { "tipo1", "tipo2" };

// Tupla
var datos = (imgs, cap, tipos);

// Creas el objeto
var album = new Photo.PhotoAlbum(datos);
```

Incluso podrías reemplazar la tupla `datos` por un tipo (struct o class) que tú hayas creado.

Si no te compila, es porque tu versión de C# es antigua pero se soluciona si declaras explicitamente el tipo [Tupla](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Como la seda. Muchas gracias.